# Finding a basis for the columnspace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find a linearly independent set of vectors that spans the same subspace of $R^4$ as that spanned by the vectors -
>   $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 \\
> -4 \\
> -1 \\
> -2 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> ,
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 7 \\
> -2 \\
> 7 \\
> 2 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> ,
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 2 \\
> 3 \\
> 2 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> ,
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 3 \\
> -2 \\
> 2 \\
> 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

So I start by reducing the matrix of these vectors to echelon form -

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -7 & -3 & -2 \\
0 & 21 & 7 &  7 \\
0 & -30 & -10 & -10 \\
0 & -12 & -4 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -7 & -3 & -2 \\
0 & 3 & 1 &  1 \\
0 & -3 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & -3 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -7 & -3 & -2 \\
0 & 3 & 1 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then I get $x_2 = -\frac{1}{3}x_3 - \frac{1}{3}x_4$ and $x_1 = \frac{2}{3}x_3 - \frac{1}{3}x_4$

So this gives me the linearly independent vectors below that span the same subspaces as the original vectors -

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\frac {2}{3} \\
-\frac {1}{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-\frac {1}{3} \\
-\frac {1}{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

But when I enter this answer I am told it is incorrect...anyone able to see where Im going wrong?

Comment: Try writing the first of your four vectors as a linear combination of the two you derived. It is impossible.

Comment: @Samuel Reid: isn't it obvious that row 3 and 4 and linear combinations of row 2? just thought Id save myself writing in another matrix.

Comment: @AlexBecker: can you see where I am going wrong though, I can't pinpoint where I am making a mistake.

Comment: I am certified as blind as a bat.

Comment: @Brian_CS: (Edit, too late; deleted old comment and fixed it) What you are doing is finding a basis for the nullspace. What you are supposed to be doing is finding a basis for the columnspace. The columnspace does not equal the nullspace, and elementary row operations do not respect the columnspace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start with a matrix whose columns are the vectors you have.

Then reduce this matrix to row-echelon form.

A basis for the columnspace of the original matrix is given by the columns **in the original matrix** that correspond to the pivots in the row-echelon form.

What you are doing does not really make sense because elementary row operations **do not** preserve the column space, but you are looking for a basis of the column space. In the end, what you are finding is a basis for the **nullspace** of the matrix, but what you are looking for is a basis for the **columnspace**.

Now, the nullspace and the rowspace are orthogonal to each other (in fact, orthogonal complements), so you *could* use your two vectors to find a basis for the column space, but it's too much extra work.

So: starting with the matrix of vectors you have,

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
2 & 7 & 1 & 3\\
-4 & -2 & 2 & -2\\
-1 & 7 & 3 & 2\\
-2 & 2 & 2 & 0
\end{array}\right) &\to
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1 & 7 & 3 & 2\\
-4 & -2 & 2 & -2\\
2 & 7 & 1 & 3\\
-2 & 2 & 2 & 0
\end{array}\right) \to 
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1 & 7 & 3 & 2\\
0 & -30 & -10 & -10\\
0 & 21 & 7 & 7\\
0 & -12 & -4 & -4
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1 & 7 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 3 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 3 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 3 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right) \to
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
\color{red}{-1} & 7 & 3 & 2\\
0 & \color{red}3 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}$$
(Same thing you had)

Now, since the pivots of the row echelon form are in columns 1 and 2 (marked in red), that means that columns 1 and 2 *of the original matrix* are independent and span the column space. That is, you can take
$$\left(\begin{array}{r}
2 \\-4\\-1\\-2\end{array}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad
\left(\begin{array}{r}
7\\-2 \\ 7 \\ 2
\end{array}\right).$$
It should be easy to see that the two vectors are linearly independent. Also, 
$$\left(\begin{array}{r}
1\\2\\3\\2\end{array}\right) = -\frac{2}{3}\left(\begin{array}{r}
2\\-4\\-1\\-2\end{array}\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{r}7\\-2\\7\\2\end{array}\right)$$
and
$$\left(\begin{array}{r}
3\\-2\\2\\0\end{array}\right) = \frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{r}
2\\-4\\-1\\-2\end{array}\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{r}7\\-2\\7\\2\end{array}\right)$$
so the first two columns span the same space as all four.

The reason this works is that any linear combination between the columns is respected by elementary row operations (equivalently: elementary row operations do not change the nullspace).  Since the columns that contain the pivots are necessarily a basis for the columnspace of the row-echelon form, the corresponding columns in the original form a basis. In fact, you can find the expressions I found above to show the other two columns are linear combinations by looking in the reduced-row echelon form instead of the original matrix; this is often easier.

This method *extracts* a subset of your original set that is a basis for the span of the set; that is, it gives you a way to pare your set down to a basis. If all you need is to find *a* basis, you can also begin by putting the vectors as the *rows* of a matrix and then performing elementary row operations until you get a matrix in row-echelon form. The (transpose of the) rows that contain the pivots *in the row-echelon form* give you a basis for the span of the original vectors. The reason *this* works is that elementary row operations don't change the row space, and the rows that contain the pivots are clearly a basis for the row space of the row-echelon form of the matrix. But you would not look for the nullspace in any case.

Comment: Excellent answer, cheers mate.